# Understanding the notation of academic article

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am in doubt to understand the notation in this academic article below. This type of notation of equation (1) is not found in the books I study in economics.

For example, in the book of Casella Statististic Inference this notation does not appear and I am having difficulty "reading" this equation.

This type of nottion I will have on Intermediate Probability books?

[image]

One of my doubts is to understand how he calculates the conditional expectation of the squared difference between a random variable $x_{t+h}(r)$ and a probability function $p_{s,t+h|t}(r)$ ???

Could you suggest readings to help me better understand these notations? In other articles I also have difficulty understanding notations. I think economics books do not really address these issues.

This is the article:

https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/conferences/shared/pdf/20160603_forecasting/Paper_10_Sekhposyan.pdf

Many thanks, guys!